# Align Text in Table header after rotating it 90 or 270 degree

Tags: html, css

I had rotated the the header text in a table but now the problem is, I am not able to center it.
It should be aligned center but it just starts from the center and looks very weird. I can't to post image as this is  my first question.

My Css:

```
<style>
.myClass {height: 350px; 
column-width: 20px;
text-align: left;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    g-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    } 
</style>
```

and My Html Table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="myClass">Secondlongheadear
        </th>
        
        <th class="myClass">Secondlongheadear
        </th>
        <th class="myClass">Second long headear
        </th>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's `g-origin`? Maybe you wanted `transform-origin`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava  I was just searching for code to align it. Dont know the exact meaning of this. transform-origin is also not working.  please help to align it if possible

Answer (score 0):

```css
.myClass {
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  padding: 8vh;
}

table {
  font-size: calc(1vh + 2vw);
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
}

table tr:last-child {
  max-height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Your Table
    <caption>
      <thead>
        <th class="myClass">Secondlong headear
        </th>

        <th class="myClass">Secondlong headear
        </th>

        <th class="myClass">Second long headear
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>tbody</td>
          <td>tbody</td>
          <td>tbody</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <td class="costam">foo</td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>foo</td>
      </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for  Reply,  but  "writing-mode: vertical-rl" is not supported by all browsers. I already had tried this.